# How can I remove someone else's computer from my wireless network?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

I want to remove someone else's computer from my wireless network.  How do I access my router to see if I can block their MAC address.  I have Windows 7.

Comment: Have you checked your router's manual? Have you tried the typical IP addresses like 192.168.0.1? Also, please note that MAC addresses can be spoofed, so if the person in question is determined enough, MAC blocking will not keep them out of your wireless network. Instead, simply change your wireless password and don't disclose it to them. Make sure you're using WPA2 encryption, while you're at it.

Comment: The quality of this question is pretty low because it lacks detail. You will need to [edit] your question to provide more details about your router and what you've already tried in order to get any useful answer here. Until then, answers will be vague and generic.

Answer (score 2):

Since your networks integrity has been compromised (because someone who shouldn't have access does have access) the best course of action would be to change your wireless password.

If this is not possible for some reason, check your routers manual if you can blacklist certain MAC addresses. You can find the MAC address of the offending host with:

```
ping ip.of.offending.host
arp -a
```

And look up the MAC address in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Log into you Wireless router using the gateway address usually 192.168.X.X. Gateway address can be verified using, going to a command prompt and using the IPCONFIG /ALL command. To access your router launch your browser and in the address bar type the address in there. If you have never changed your Admin password depending on the model of router you will find default password listed in the manual. First step is to change this password.

Second I would check to see it your using WEP / if so discontinue and switch to WPA or  WPA2 depending on your router. Then change your Wireless password, use a non-dictionary password.

To block his MAC address apply a filter and set up allow only these MAC addresses to connect to this router, and add only your MAC addresses, this will prevent this person from attempting using a unknown MAC address.

For added security I would change the SSID and disable broadcast which will prevent casual people from seeing you router.